# How do I watch channel in Google Calendar API using node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

```
module.exports.hook = (req, res) => {
  resourceId = req.headers['x-goog-resource-id'];
  console.log('received signal from Google');
  console.log('listen on channel ID: ', req.headers['x-goog-channel-id']);
  console.log('and resource ID is:', req.headers['x-goog-resource-id']);
  listEvents(auth);
};

module.exports.createChannel = (id, callback) => {
  const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth });
  calendar.events.watch({ // post method
    auth,
    calendarId: 'primary',
    resource: {
      id,
      type: 'web_hook',
      address: `https://super.eu.ngrok.io/notifications?id=${id}`,
    },
  }, (error, result) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    callback(result);
  });
};
```

This is what I tried. I couldn't find any specific info. Please help out. Thanks in advance. I'm quite new to Google API's.

Comment: Can you add any details like error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push
I want to receive notifications for any change in events in my Google Calendar. There are no samples given in the documentation for how to do it. I couldn't figure out a way  for it.

Comment: @Vishal did you find a solution? I need to listen for posts from the events.watch

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide any details on the error you encounter.
Anyway I think you should try whith an address without any URL parameters:
`https://super.eu.ngrok.io/notifications` instead of `https://super.eu.ngrok.io/notifications?id=${id}`
It's useless to set your unique identifier in the URL. You will retrieve it in the watch response.

Check also that your auth object is valid.
It's working for me.

```
const response = await google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth }).events.watch({
      calendarId: 'primary',
      resource: {
        id,
        address: 'https://super.eu.ngrok.io/notifications',
        type: 'web_hook',
        params: {
          ttl: '30000',
        },
      },
    }));
```

More information here:

- https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push#renewing-notification-channels
- https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch